# VBA ShapeRange.Rotation Property randomly stops working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to rotate a shape.  Below is the relevant snippet.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes.Range(Array("Down Arrow 8")).Select
Selection.ShapeRange.Rotation =  90 + Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H8")
```

My problem is that the last line randomly works and randomly doesn't!  I used to have it as a number (instead of a to string) but this refuses to work!  It worked fine, then I made some changes to the macro and then it helpfully returned Error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method.  I fiddled around, debugged, etc (without ever changing the code) and it started working!  Then I made some more changes and it stopped working and it seems to have stopped working for good.  I literally copied this code from a recorded macro.

What I have tried:
Using CStr() to convert the value to a string
Declaring a variable and using the variable

What I really don't understand is why it would work without me changing the code and them stop working without me changing the code (i.e. the relevant lines)

Comment: Use the actual Shape object, not the Selection. The selection isn't always going to be a Shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things.  First, avoid select.  It isn't necessary and will save you a lot of headache and time in the future.  Second, you can reference the shape by its name right from the `Shapes` object, assuming you are only intending to rotate one shape with the code.  Finally, are you certain the value in `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H8")` is numeric?  If not, this could cause an error.  The code below handles the first two issues.  Beyond that, we'll need to see more code to determine the error.

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Shapes("Down Arrow 8").Rotation = 90 + Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H8")
```

Comment: That seems to have solved the problem.  Yes, The cell will always be numeric (Actually, my bad, I didn't put in .Value, since it is using a formula to search for a value).  My problem was I copied the code from a Macro, so the above was the best I could do.  I'm a decent programmer but wholly new to VBA, so I don't really know the syntax.  And, I didn't like using Select, but I didn't know how to put it like you put it above.  Thanks!

Comment: @JeremyMorren no worries at all.  We all start out using Select until someone shows us the path to the light.  Check out [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate#t=201607271311166684891) for some more detail on avoiding select.  Happy coding!

Comment: @JeremyMorren and, if your problem is now solved, please mark the answer as accepted to remove this from the unanswered question queue